# Using symfony with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, symfony1

I am trying to create a website using Symfony and PostgreSQL. I cant find any documentation that shows how to do this. All the documentation assumes the backend db is mySQL.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer (took me about an hour to figure this out) is:

1. Modify database.yml as described [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases)  (see under Propel or Doctrine)
2. (assuming you're using the Propel ORM like I am) Modify propel.ini  as shown below (undocumented AFAIK)

Look for a section in your propel.ini names ;mysql options

comment the mysql options out - otherwise the generated SQL is a mix of postgresql and mysql - which confuses the hell out of psql.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Doctrine, just use a dsn for pgSQL in your databases.yml, like this :

```
pgsql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1
```

It use the PDO syntax. Check the [Doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/introduction-to-connections/en) and [PDO documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses 3rd-parties ORMs for DB communication which provide abstraction layer over RDBMS specific architecture. Basically everything you have to do is to change Doctrine's/Propel's driver name, so in `/config/databaes.yml` set `pgsql` instead of `mysql` and you're done.