# How to change a database to postgresql with Symfony 2.0?

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I have a Symfony2 project under Debian. What are the steps to change my database to postgresql ?

*Note: The question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840061/using-symfony-with-postgresql), but it is with symfony 1.4, I believe.*

Comment: If you hope use two connections,just take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440403/how-to-create-2-connections-mysql-and-postgresql-with-doctrine2-in-symfony2

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Install postgresql under debian:

```
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client
apt-get install php5-pgsql
adduser mypguser
su - postgres
psql
CREATE USER mypguser WITH PASSWORD 'mypguserpass';
CREATE DATABASE mypgdatabase;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mypgdatabase to mypguser;
\q
```

In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, add: (this is in fact optional)

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.so
```

Change the symfony apps/config/paramters.ini file:

```
[parameters]
    database_driver:    pdo_pgsql
    database_host:      localhost
    database_port:      null
    database_name:      mypgdatabase
    database_user:      mypguser
    database_password:  mypguserpass
```

Relaod your project:

```
php bin/vendors update
php app/console assets:install web
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
chmod 777 -R app/cache app/logs
```

You're done!

**References:**

[Symfony documentation for configuring databases](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html)

[Postgresql installation under debian](http://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#Installation)

Comment: shouldn't you tell postgres to run as mypguser? Or why are you doing adduser?

Comment: @Hendrik, you're right, there's no need to do the adduser.