# Symfony 3 project with PostgreSQL as DB

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I am setting up my Symfony 3 project (using Netbeans IDE) and want to use PostgreSQL as my database instead of MySQL. After some time online I have found a few potential solutions (one of which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588646/how-to-change-a-database-to-postgresql-with-symfony-2-0) but this one does not seem to work for me). So:

1. My symfony 3 project is running on the local MAMP server
2. PostgreSQL server is running on the local machine as well
3. I have setup my `parameters.yml` file as per below:

```
- database_driver: pdo_pgsql
- database_host: localhost
- database_port: 5432
- database_name: mypgdatabase
- database_user: mypguser
- database_password:  mypguserpass
```

The error that i am getting when generating entities is:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
>
> An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>
> could not find driver
>
> [PDOException]
>               
>     could not find driver

Been trying to figure this one out for a few days now so any help will he highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have PHP’s PDO pgsql module installed ?

Comment: Not sure, how would i check for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked in your "php.ini" file that you have this:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.so
```

The php.ini file location might depend on which operating system you are using, if it's a mac run:

```
$ locate php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks Alvin Bunk, i am using mama server on OS X and non of the above is in my php.ini file. Next question is who do i get those extantions installed. the one that i do have tho is ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll however it is commented out and extension=pdo.so is missing as such.

Comment: Try uncommenting `;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` (remove the semicolon) and see what happens. You might need to restart Apache.

Comment: uncommented and restarted MAMP, getting these errors now: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You might have to install PostgreSQL support for PHP. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588174/enabling-postgresql-support-in-php-on-mac-os-x) and the answer in particular. My original answer is correct though, and you should mark it as the correct answer. You need to figure out how to enable the `php_pdo_pgsql.so` module.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to check for PHP modules

> php -m | grep 'pdo\|pgsql'

It looks like you need both PDO_pgsql and pgsql